# Is there any app to save all my health data?

Tags: health

I'm looking for an application to save all my health records, like if I had an appointment with doctor today then I can login into application and show doctor all my blood test reports, x-rays, CT scan and other medical records.

Comment: Whether this would be possible would depend on two things, an app existing and the medical policy and laws of your area. It is unusual for a patient to have their own records. See these articles with a US perspective. http://medicaleconomics.modernmedicine.com/medical-economics/news/patient-records-struggle-ownership "The Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) does not specify ownership, and state laws are inconsistent." and http://www.physicianspractice.com/blog/hipaa-compliance-access-practice-staff-medical-records

Comment: @RichardChambers Patients based in the US may request that medical records. If a medical professional fails to provide the medical records reading 30 days of the request, they violate the HIPAA. I've already filed 2 HIPAA complains: the law is clear. [How to report an infraction of the HIPAA requirements?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5601/31). The ownership is a different issue.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt so what does it say about medical records? The question you link to is about lab results which is only a part of medical records.

Comment: @RichardChambers HIPAA covers all aspects of medical records.

Answer (score 1):

There exist several web services for patients to manage their health data, e.g. from https://www.healthit.gov/patients-families/maintain-your-medical-record:

[image]

The main issue is that medical data come with a variety of formats, sometimes proprietary.

---

Patients based in the US may request their medical records from their medical providers. If a medical professional fails to provide the medical records reading 30 days of the request, they violate the HIPAA. I've already filed 2 HIPAA complains: the law is clear. I encourage you to exercise your rights as a patient. [How to report an infraction of the HIPAA requirements?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5601/31)